# How to use php_CURL to acess a website

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, simple-html-dom, goutte

This  is  the  usual  mile  calculator page  on  emirates  website  and  if  i  want  to  access  certain  fields   from  DOM  of  this  page  by  passing  certain  parameters  ,then  which  library  would  be  required  using  php  and  how?
I  researched  the  following  two  libraries  :
1.Goutte
2.Simplehtml  dom
I  used  both  of  them  and  I  am   only  able  to search  for particular  strings  and return  yes  if  they  exists  otherwise  no.The  link  is  this  one:

http://www.emirates.com/account/english/miles-calculator/miles-calculator.aspx?org=BOM&dest=JFK&trvc=0&h=7b1dc440b5eecbda143bd8e7b9ef53a27e364b

If  i  wanted  to  know  that  "How  many  mile  will  I   earn  from  US  to  India  depending  on  "Class  of  fare",Ticket  type,Skywards  tier  and  Type  of  fair.Don't   provide  me  code,just  guide   me   how  I  can  load  the  dom  using  any  existing  library  and  retrieve  my  queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_web_page( $url )
    {               
            $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true, 
            CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true, 
        );

        $ch      = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
        $content = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        return $content;
}

echo get_web_page("http://www.emirates.com/account/english/miles-calculator/miles-calculator.aspx?org=BOM&dest=JFK&trvc=0&h=7b1dc440b5eecbda143bd8e7b9ef53a27e364b");
```

Comment: @alreadycoded.comthanks  for  your  reply.however  could  you  explain  how  i  will  pass  parameters  or  options  using  curl